# Who embeds my Widgets? (Or how to get the URL of the parent frame)

Tags: javascript, http, iframe

Is there I way to get the URL of the parent frame from within an iframe? I know you can't do this using JavaScript (or is there?). Is there a way to do it server-side?

Or is the only solution that we change our widget embed codes so that they include some JavaScript that communicates the `window.location` to the iframe (`postMessage`/changing the location hash of the iframe)?

Comment: Server side you can check the referrer.

Comment: @dystroy Are you sure this works in every browser? Also there are quite some users that suppress referrers.